# How to prove $\sqrt{1000} < x < 1000$?

Tags: inequality, fractions

I have been given that

$$x = \frac 21 \times \frac 43 \times \frac 65 \times \frac 87 \times \cdots \times \frac {996}{995} \times \frac{998}{997} \times \frac {1000}{999}$$

How can I prove that $\sqrt{1000} < x < 1000$?

Comment: Try to rewrite $x=1 \cdot \frac23 \cdot \frac45 \cdot ... \cdot \frac{996}{997} \cdot \frac{998}{999} \cdot 1000$. What do you see?

Comment: The right hand side inequality is evident.

Comment: The left hand side can be calculated by EXCEL. The product is 39,64318253, but the $\sqrt{1000}$ is 31,6227766.

Comment: @kmitov Darn, they are close, so this is going to be interesting.

Comment: I do not think that 39 and 31 are so close.

Comment: @kmitov Ok, not **that** close, but close enough for it to be problematic in my manipulations.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

\begin{align}
x^2 &= \left(\frac 21 \times \frac 21\right) \times \left(\frac 43 \times \frac 43\right) \times \cdots \times \left(\frac{1000}{999} \times \frac {1000}{999}\right) \\
&\ge \left(\frac 21 \times \frac 32\right) \times \left(\frac 43 \times \frac 54\right) \times \cdots \times \left(\frac{1000}{999} \times \frac {1001}{1000}\right) \\
&= 1001
\end{align}

Comment: The inequality $\frac{n+1}n\ge\frac{n+2}{n+1}$ is immediate upon subtracting $1$ from both sides.

Comment: Ah, that was basically perfect for the problem at hand.